# Come si può esprimere, in modo colloquiale, "I can't speak to..."?

Tags: translation

Qualche tempo fa stavo utilizzando, per la prima volta, una specie di strofinaccio che qualcuno aveva fatto all'uncinetto. Lavando i piatti mi sono detto qualcosa sulla falsariga di "sembra efficace, ma  **I can't speak to the durability...**", il che è una maniera lievemente spiritosa di esprimere "ho qualche incertezza riguardo alla durabilità" di questo strofinaccio di fattura casalinga.

Cercavo di trovare una maniera semplice e colloquiale di rendere questa idea in italiano e mi è venuta la seguente:

> quanto alla durabilità, non saprei...

Che cosa ne pensate? Se non vi piace, mi potreste suggerire qualcosa di meglio?

Comment: ”Sembra efficace, ma durerà?”

Comment: “...ma sulla durata non (ci) giurerei.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Durabilità* è un termine che esiste ma non così comune nel linguaggio parlato.
Ti basti pensare che sulla Treccani <sup>[[1](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/durabilita/)]</sup> trovi esempi in Leonardo e Leopardi...

Potresti invece usare il verbo (meglio al congiuntivo presente)

> Quanto **duri** poi non saprei...

o anche `quanto possa durare`.

Answer (score 0):

Io lo esprimerei con un giro di parole: "Sembra efficace, ma non so quanto possa durare".

O anche "Sembra efficace, *finché dura*".

Volendo scherzare, io direi "Sembra efficace; *duràlla, disse il canìno*..." - ma è un modo di dire probabilmente caduto in disuso, e non molto noto fuori dalla Toscana<sup>1</sup>.

Una versione altrettanto scherzosa, e più comprensibile, potrebbe essere "Sembra efficace, quanto ha di garanzia?" o "...ma non so quanto duri la garanzia".

---

<sub>(1) ci sono più versioni di questa storia. La più riportata la vuole riferita a un "canino" (ossia un cagnolino) che, passando la vita a mangiare e dormire, fu chiamato dal proprietario *Duràlla*, cioè "finché dura". Una versione più salace vuole che *Duràlla!* fosse il commento del cane, di piccola taglia, mentre si accoppiava con una cagna assai più grande di lui. In effetti una variante del modo di dire sostituisce *Duràlla* con *Avénne* (averne, cioè "Ce ne fosse!"). Lo stesso modo di dire ha una versione più pessimistica, nel caso che si sospetti che le cose stiano per volgere al peggio: *Speriamo bene, disse il rospo* (il detto prosegue "*...ma (vedo) il contadino (che) aguzza il palo* - cioè si prepara a montare i cannicci, operazione durante la quale capitava che qualche rospo che sonnecchiava nel fango ci andasse di mezzo)</sub>

Comment: anche "Sulla durata, non garantisco."

Comment: Da non toscano mi è un po' misterioso “duràlla, disse il canìno”... Potresti spiegare? “Canìno” si riferisce a un cagnolino?

Comment: Grazie, @LSerni!